# Got error 'Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource' when using a ComboBox in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a WPF application, I created a ComboBox in the MainWindow.xaml file and I'm trying to show the Property 'username' of all the instances of Person in the ComboBox. I get the error at line 41 : Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

The code for the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //private string filePath = @"source\repos\WpfApplication\LocalUsernames.txt";
        List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializePeople();
        }

        public void InitializePeople()
        {
            //if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
            //{
            //    File.CreateText(filePath);
            //}

            People.Add(new Person() { username = "Bob", password = "1234"});

            myDropdownMenu.ItemsSource = People;
            myDropdownMenu.DataContext = "username";
        }
    }
}
```

Person class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    class Person
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the MainWindow.xaml code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="myDropdownMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ComboBox Width="120"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Remove the inner `<ComboBox Width="120"/>`.

Comment: Besides that, setting `myDropdownMenu.DataContext = "username"` also makes no sense. In case you wanted to show the value of the username property in the ComboBox, set `DisplayMemberPath="username"` in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Creating another ComboBox inside the ComboBox makes no sense. Remove that.

If you need to display only one of the properties of the collection elements in the list, then the property name can be specified by the `DisplayMemberPath` property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myDropdownMenu"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
          DisplayMemberPath="username" />
```